# Synology 712+ Added larger drives but available space not showing

Tags: network-attached-storage, synology

I have a Synology 712+ with a SHR volume on the system.

I had two 4tb drives and replaced them with 8tb drives.

The system shows both drives as 7.28 tb but do not allow me to use more than 4tbs of space. I replaced one drive, let the system rebuild, then replaced another and let the system rebuild. Now a week later still only 4tb of storage available.

Why is this? I'm trying a system update but I'm guessing thats not going to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to rebuild the array and wait for it to complete. This took a few days.